# Creating do-while loop to prompt user if they want to enter another ISBN

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, isbn

So as a project for my class I am required to make a program that has the user enter the first n digits of an ISBN number and responds with the tenth digit. I have searched endlessly for something that will allow my program to ask the user if they want to run the program again and then have it run the program again if they enter 'yes' or 'Y'. What I have found hasn't worked, usually it just ends up looping "Would you like to enter another ISBN' without actually having them enter an ISBN. My code is below, thank you guys for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ISBNCheckSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        // limiter 
        int isbn10 = 9;
        // to take in response of user
        long userResponse;
        // accumulator 
        int ISBnNum = 1;
        //current count of ISBN
        long isbnCount = 0;
        // This is used to multiply the userresponse by 1,2,3... up to 9
        int multiplier = 1;

        while (ISBnNum <= isbn10) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please ISBN number  " + ISBnNum);
            //to enter the User response
            userResponse = keyboard.nextInt();
            //Multiply the user response by multiplier variable
            userResponse = userResponse * multiplier;
            //add to accumulator 
            ISBnNum = ISBnNum + 1;
            // put user into final answer
            isbnCount = isbnCount + userResponse;
            // increase multiplier
            multiplier = multiplier + 1;
        }

        long checkSum;
        checkSum = isbnCount % 11;
        System.out.println(checkSum);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You would benefit from using proper indentation. I've done it for you this time, but please take the time to format your code properly next time. Looks like you have an extra closing bracket. Also, it doesn't look like you have actually tried what you're describing. I think what you're looking for is a while loop that repeats while some user input is "Y".

Comment: Thanks for that, I am pretty new to Java and coding in general. I kind of figured that was what I was looking for but I haven't found how to implement it yet. That is why I came here.

Comment: Also, please respect java code conventions: ISBnNum is not a good name for a variable as it starts with a capital I. Take a look at this https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html

Comment: @Tokioi Take a look here: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/tutorial/java-while-loop

Comment: Yeah, it was something I meant to fix but when I got working on this part I kind of forgot. I adjusted it in my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I have changed the iSBnNum variable name):

```
    boolean askAgain = true;
    while (askAgain) {
        iSBnNum = 1;
        while (iSBnNum <= isbn10) {
            System.out.println("Please ISBN number  " + iSBnNum);
            // to enter the User response
            userResponse = keyboard.nextInt();
            // Multiply the user response by multiplier variable
            userResponse = userResponse * multiplier;
            // add to accumulator
            iSBnNum = iSBnNum + 1;
            // put user into final answer
            isbnCount = isbnCount + userResponse;
            // increase multiplier
            multiplier = multiplier + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Ask again (Y/N)?");
        String answer = keyboard.next();

        askAgain = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Antonio. This got it working. I would also like to thank everyone for helping make my code look better.